# Any links or pointers where I can learn about various data types available in ruby(on rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Some datatypes which I commonly use are ***string ,integer*** while creating models
***text_field, text_area and password_field*** while creating forms inside views.

Data types to use with models are my first priority .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few good sites for this. I recommend this as a reference :

http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/

The only major pitfall I ever landed in with datatypes with the different between bignum and int . Other than it's all very straightforward.

Comment: Nice collection,is there a similar link to list the form types which I can use in ruby *.html.erb files ?? Thanks in advance